Blazor Real Time updates
I am trying to use blazor for a project I'm working on that will be a real time dashboard for tracking.  So far, in my POC's I haven't been able to get Blazor to automatically refresh without an onclick event.  I took the sample weather app and tried modifying it to update the weather every 3 seconds and this only works if I refresh the browser.  I need it to update without a refresh.  Any ideas?  I've called statehaschanged to no avail.
@page "/weather"
@attribute [StreamRendering]

<PageTitle>Weather</PageTitle>

<h1>Weather</h1>

<p>This component demonstrates showing data.</p>

@if (forecasts == null)
{
<p><em>Loading...</em></p>
}
else
{
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Temp. (C)</th>
            <th>Temp. (F)</th>
            <th>Summary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var forecast in forecasts)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@forecast.Date.ToShortDateString()</td>
                <td>@forecast.TemperatureC</td>
                <td>@forecast.TemperatureF</td>
                <td>@forecast.Summary</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
}

@code {
private WeatherForecast[]? forecasts;
private Timer? _timer;

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    // Initialize the weather data and start updating 
 immediately
    UpdateWeatherForecast();

    // Set up the timer to update every 3 seconds
    _timer = new Timer(OnTimerElapsed, null, TimeSpan.Zero, 
TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
}

// Timer callback method (synchronous)
private void OnTimerElapsed(object? state)
{
    // Log to ensure that this method is being called
    Console.WriteLine("Timer elapsed, updating weather 
data...");

    // Call the async method to update weather forecast
    InvokeAsync(UpdateWeatherForecast);
}

// Asynchronous method to update the weather forecast
private async Task UpdateWeatherForecast()
{
    // Log to track state changes
    Console.WriteLine("Updating weather forecast...");

    // Generate new weather data
    var startDate = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now);
    var summaries = new[] { "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", 
"Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching" };
    forecasts = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = startDate.AddDays(index),
            TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = summaries[Random.Shared.Next(summaries.Length)]
        }).ToArray();

    // Log to check if data is being set
    Console.WriteLine("Forecast data updated.");

    // Ensure the UI refreshes
    InvokeAsync(() =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Calling StateHasChanged...");
        StateHasChanged();
    });

    // Yield control back to avoid blocking
    await Task.Yield();
}

// Cleanup the timer when the component is disposed
public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
{
    if (_timer != null)
    {
        _timer.Dispose();
        Console.WriteLine("Timer disposed.");
    }
}

// Weather forecast model
private class WeatherForecast
{
    public DateOnly Date { get; set; }
    public int TemperatureC { get; set; }
    public string? Summary { get; set; }
    public int TemperatureF => 32 + (int)(TemperatureC / 
0.5556);
}
}


Remove the StreamRendering attribute and add @rendermode InteractiveServer instead

Thanks for the answer.  I tried that but still have the same results.  I have to manually refresh the browser for the UI to update.

Actually, I was wrong.  This is working.  Thank you!

There are various issues in the code you provided.  For the record, here's a cleaner version:
@page "/weather"
@implements IDisposable
@rendermode InteractiveServer

<PageTitle>Weather</PageTitle>

<h1>Weather</h1>

<p>This component demonstrates showing data.</p>

@if (forecasts == null)
{
    <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
}
else
{
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Temp. (C)</th>
                <th>Temp. (F)</th>
                <th>Summary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var forecast in forecasts)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@forecast.Date.ToShortDateString()</td>
                    <td>@forecast.TemperatureC</td>
                    <td>@forecast.TemperatureF</td>
                    <td>@forecast.Summary</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}

@code {
    private WeatherForecast[]? forecasts;
    private Timer? _timer;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        _timer = new Timer(OnTimerElapsed, null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
    }

    private async void OnTimerElapsed(object? state)
    {
        await this.InvokeAsync(UpdateWeatherForecastAsync);
    }

    private async Task UpdateWeatherForecastAsync()
    {
        // Fake an async data call
        await Task.Delay(10);

        var startDate = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now);
        var summaries = new[] { "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching" };

        forecasts = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = startDate.AddDays(index),
                TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = summaries[Random.Shared.Next(summaries.Length)]
            }).ToArray();

            this.StateHasChanged();
    }

    // Sync version: there's no async disposal work to do.
    // also added the implements at the top of the page
    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_timer != null)
        {
            _timer.Dispose();
            Console.WriteLine("Timer disposed.");
        }
    }

    // Weather forecast model
    private class WeatherForecast
    {
        public DateOnly Date { get; set; }
        public int TemperatureC { get; set; }
        public string? Summary { get; set; }
        public int TemperatureF => 32 + (int)(TemperatureC / 0.5556);
    }
}

